# Google is not crawling React Dynamic Page because its SPA

Tags: reactjs

I created a website with React, now I am facing an issue related to SEO crawling, the crawler can't find the source code for different meta tags for different pages because it's a single-page application. I used React Helmet package for dynamic meta's but was not able to see them in the "view source code" option in the browser. And google needs source code to crawl the page but in this case, there is no source code exists for multiple pages except for the home page.

I have tried react-snap package but not working as expected .

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Yes this is a challenge with SEO and runtime content creation via React. You can think of server side rendering (more effort) or writting an html file with enough SEO tags with js code

Comment: Google's bot supports react AFAIK. Its bing which doesnt